# applet does not appear on separate window

Tags: java, applet

I used tomcat5.5 to access the server, and then logged in succssfully. 
Then I accessed one page and it said " applet will appear in a separate window. 
 Note that the Graph Author requires the Sun Java plugin, version 1.4 or newer. 
 Please be patient, it may take a while to download all the classes of this applet. "
I waited for like 15 mins, and still there was nothing.

**Does it mean that I need to wait more than 15 mins? or is there any problem on my computer?**

I installed newest version of java sdk 8.

I tried this on IE, Firefox, Chrome, and I changed all settings that enables java scripting in browser.

*One thing is that when I start the window it says that tomcat is not working?(or is not avaliable, sth like that). However after I enable service, it works so that I was able to access the server.